How do I copy files from Azure Blob Storage to an Azure SQL database?
I have files in Azure Blob Storage created daily that I need to copy to an Azure SQL database. Sometimes Azure Blob Storage or Azure SQL fails, so how do I copy files without loss to an Azure SQL database daily with Python?
I have tried some libraries:
import os
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
import polars as pl
from tqdm import tqdm
from datetime import datetime
import sys
from azure.storage.blob import ContainerClient
from azure.core.exceptions import ResourceNotFoundError, ClientAuthenticationError
import re
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import pickle
import io
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import urllib
import logging
import sys
import time
import sqlalchemy
from typing import Sequence, Hashable
from collections import defaultdict

I need a solution in Python, not Azure tools because Azure Data Factory is not working on .parquet files.

What is the error you are getting while using ADF?

no error on ADF just stucked and cant see source .parquet list from azure containers. but see csv files. its too strange. so i need to write whole process by python is more flexible to me.

you should create parquet dataset to show parquet files

can you try with it once?

yes of course. so i gave up on azure and try it by python on VM. and i read all blogs and reddit and stackoverflow but  Azure didnt fix this .parquet files bug for years. sad

can you add code you have tried?

i tried on ADF UI interface. not code.

what the error message you are getting in ADF?

You can use below python code to achieve your requirement.
Here, I have built the Blob storage connection using connection string. You can do it as per your requirement.
Make sure you install the below packages before running your code:
SQLAlchemy
pandas
pyarrow
fastparquet
pyodbc
azure-storage-blob
tabulate

And also install the ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server in your file location.
After building the connection with Blob storage and creating SQL engine, firstly, this will get the list of parquet files in the given location. After that, it will filter out the files which are uploaded on that day and will read each file as a pandas data frame and writes the same to SQL database tables.
Code:
import os
import pandas as pd
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
from sqlalchemy import create_engine,text
import urllib
from datetime import datetime,timezone

server   = '<server_name>.database.windows.net'
database = '<SQL_database_name>'
username = '<Username>'
password = '<password>'   
driver   = '{ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server}'

conn = f"""Driver={driver};Server=tcp:{server},1433;Database={database};
Uid={username};Pwd={password};Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;"""

params = urllib.parse.quote_plus(conn)
conn_str = 'mssql+pyodbc:///?autocommit=true&odbc_connect={}'.format(params)

# Create SQL Engine
sql_engine = create_engine(conn_str, echo=True)

# Get the current day at 12 AM
curr_day=datetime.now(timezone.utc).replace(hour = 0, minute = 0, second = 0, microsecond = 0)


# Create Azure Blob storage connection
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string("<Connection_string>")
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client("<Your_container_name>")

# Get list of parquet files and the last modified dates of those
list_files = [blob.name for blob in container_client.list_blobs() if blob.name.endswith(".parquet")]
lastmodifieddate_files=[blob_service_client.get_blob_client("dec24thsourceparquet",blob=blob_name).get_blob_properties()['last_modified'] for blob_name in list_files]

parquet_files=[]

# If the last modified date of the parquet files is greater than the current date(12AM), then you can copy that file
for i in range(len(list_files)):
    if lastmodifieddate_files[i]>curr_day:
        parquet_files.append(list_files[i])

for file_name in parquet_files:
    try:
        blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(file_name)
        down_stream = blob_client.download_blob()
        parquet_raw_data = down_stream.readall()
    
    # Create pandas dataframes for every parquet file
        par_df = pd.read_parquet(pd.io.common.BytesIO(parquet_raw_data))
        par_df.columns = par_df.iloc[0]  # Set the first row as column headers
        par_df = par_df[1:] # start from second after setting first row as header
        table_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(file_name))[0]
    
    # Use the SQL Engine and write the pandas dataframe to SQL tables
        par_df .to_sql(name=table_name, con=sql_engine, if_exists="replace", index=False)
        print(f"\n Successfully processed and written '{file_name}' to SQL table '{table_name}'.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error in processing '{file_name}': {e}")

You can use or schedule the same code on every day at certain time so that it copies the uploaded files on a given day. On first copy, you need to remove the filter condition of last modified date.
Output:

Data written to target SQL tables:

